# excel to pdf ignores print area and calls printer

Tags: excel, pdf, vba

This loops through a list of students, but fails on the print area, which is set and coded in the export line - it prints 130 pages for each student when it should only be one. All the printer gets called which opens a dialogue box (login 6 password) and that stops the macro - the printer is a workprinter on a network which is not always available.
Is there a way to stop the printer getting called?
And controlling the pages to the print area?

```
Option Explicit

Sub PdfExportMacro()
Dim rCell As Range, rRng As Range

'Student numbers in cells A7:A160
Set rRng = Worksheets("studentlist").Range("A7:A160") '<--| set your "students" range

With Worksheets("Feedback") '<--| reference "Feedback" worksheet
    For Each rCell In rRng '<--| loop through "students" range
    .Range("A1").Value = rCell.Value '<--| write current student number to cell A1 on Feedback sheet

       ' Export & save file as pdf using SNum as filename:
        .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, fileName:= _
        "Macintosh HD:Users:Michael:Desktop:" & rCell.Value, Quality:= _
        xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False
    Next rCell
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: The code you have there, it will always copy the feedback to Cell A1 in the Feedback sheet and then export it a new file. Meaning you will have 130 PDF files. Is this what you want? Also what print code do you use?

Comment: Hi Niclas, thanks for looking at this. The value copied to cell A1 is the student number from the student list sheet - that loop works fine, what happens is that the pdf created - which should only be 1 sheet (print area defined) from the feedback sheet is instead 130 pages of all the data on the sheets (which is huge,...). The only print code if I understand you correctly is the export format statement.

Comment: Not sure I understand. The current code will create 130 pdf files, not 130 pages. It will copy the student number to A1 in the Feedback sheet and then save it as "student number.pdf". So this is wrong according to what you want to achieve? What is the print area?

Comment: Ok, the idea is to create 160pdf files - one for each student. That loop works fine. However, when it goes to export to pdf, it actually takes all the data on all the sheets and creates a file of 128 pages of unwanted data instead of the 1 page of feedback it should use (the print area is E3:W77 on the feedback worksheet). This is the print area set on the feedback sheet - no other print areas are set.

Comment: When I run the code, I get 1 pdf per student with the student number as file name. So I do not understand how you get your output? The print area will be kinda weird if you print it to A4?

Comment: So when I run the code, the workbook has lots of other data used to build the feedback - this is being "pulled in" to the output pdf file even though the print area is set. The print area  - most students look at it on a laptop so A4 is not an issue - if they do print it it is still just legible, but small.

Comment: Could you add some screenshots for clarification?

Answer (score 1):

so I changed track - excel vba does not seem to be happy producing pdf files with the printer set as it is...
So, i changed to export an excel file per student using copy & paste special values and formats. Here is the code i did (lots stolen from other answers on here! thanks...) Any comments about improving the code are welcome - I think there is a lot of scope for that!!

```
    Option Explicit

Sub Exportmacro()
    Dim rCell As Range, rRng As Range 'define loop names
    Dim NewCaseFile As Workbook 'give a name to new work book for duplicate sheet
    Dim wks As Worksheet 'name of the copy of feedback
    Dim sPath As String
    sPath = MacScript("(path to desktop folder as string)")
'turn off screen
With Application
'        .ScreenUpdating = False  ‘only removed while testing
'        .EnableEvents = False
'        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual  ‘disabled for the moment
End With

    'Student numbers in cells A7:A160 WARNING SET TO 3 STUDENTS ONLY FOR TEST
    Set rRng = Worksheets("studentlist").Range("A7:A9")

    With Worksheets("Feedback") '<--| reference "Feedback" worksheet

        For Each rCell In rRng '<--| loop through "students" range
            .Range("A1").Value = rCell.Value '<--| write current student number to cell A1 on Feedback sheet

           'do copy ready for paste spec vals to destroy links & calculations
               ActiveSheet.Range("A2:W77").Copy

            'now open new workbook then pastespecial values and formats
             Set NewCaseFile = Workbooks.Add
             NewCaseFile.Sheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
             NewCaseFile.Sheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

            'now save as xls with student number as filename Filename:=sPath & rCell.Value & ".xlsx"
             ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=rCell.Value & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

            'now close duplicate file
             ActiveWorkbook.Close False

        Next rCell   '<-- next student number
    End With         '<-- once all done
'turn screen back on
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I am going to try this

Comment: @Will best of luck, just note that it was built for a mac, so check what you need to define a windows path. Other questions will show that.