# How to print an Excel Sheet using VBA with Nitro PDF Creator in Excel 2016

Tags: vba, excel

I am triying to print  the used range of a sheet but, i want to store it as a .pdf file, so i want to use Nitro pdf creator tool.

I already attempted with `activesheet.usedrange.print` ; but i do not know how to specify i that i want to use Nitro PDF.

Comment: Is there a reason for you not using the build in excel facilities to create a PDF? In case you didn't know, you can use somthing like `ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat` to create PDFs without using external applications.

Comment: Hi, you could look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40690592/mac-excel-vba-loop-from-list-then-export-as-pdf
But I changed direction to this saving as excel (since the printer caused problems):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40702172/excel-to-pdf-ignores-print-area-and-calls-printer