# Excel Macro to Print Presignated Print Area in Particular Order/Quantities

Tags: vba, excel, printing

I need a macro that will allow me to take a constant print area within my worksheets and print this area out (3 different print pages) in a specific order and in particular quantities of each print page.

The order I need:

```
Page 3 of the range - 1
Page 1 of the range - 3
Page 2 of the range - 2
Page 1 of the range - 13
```

I have looked for awhile now on multiple sources without finding the answer I was looking for.

Comment: Have you looked on here for any questions regarding using macros to print? Hint there are several... But you will have to customize them to match your needs...

Comment: I have yet to find any vba that specifies printing of a single page or multiple pages in a specified order. Found just about everything else that deals with printing modifcations.

Comment: Just to prove there is at least one and there are others as that is how I put much of what i use now together... https://stackoverflow.com/q/40702172/4961700

Comment: Try to use the Macro Recorder, and see what you get.

Comment: Wow, not sure why I hadn't thought about the Macro Recorder. Guess I've always used it to modify things rather than simply print them. This will do! 

Thank you, everyone!