# Looping through and Copying/Pasting rows VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to write a simple macro in xl VBA which loops through cells A1:A100 and;

1. Finds each cell with the value "HT"
2. Copies that entire row
3. Selects sheets "Records" - travels to the bottom of column A - pastes copied row
4. Loops

Here is my attempt - I'm struggling to get this to work and have been googling all sorts of different methods but can't seem to work it!

Private Sub CopyRow()

```
Dim i As Range
Sheets("Input").Select
Range("A1").Select

For Each i In Sheet9.Range("A2:A1000")
    Select Case i.Value
        Case "HT"
            Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Copy
            Sheets("Records").Select
            Range("A2").End(xlDown).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            Sheets("Input").Select

            Case Else

        End Select

    Next i
```

Appreciate any help you can give me!

Comment: I don't have an answer, but do look at a method of avoiding using "select" that I used here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/40768023/4961700

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is in that “ActiveCell.Row”, where the active cell is not, as I suppose you were assuming, the loop current cell, which is “i”, so you could use “i.Row” instead

But you may also avoid all that selecting/activating and use fully qualified range references:

```
Private Sub CopyRow()

    Dim i As Range

    With Sheets("Records") ‘reference target sheet
        For Each i In Sheet9.Range("A2:A1000") ‘loop through Sheet9 "A2:A1000" cells
            If i.Value2 = "HT" Then
                i.EntireRow.Copy
                .Cells(.Rows.Count,"A").End(xlUp).Offset(1,0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues ‘ all “dots” are making following members/object referencing the object referenced in “With...” 
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that the data is in the "Input" worksheet and that the results have to go into the "Records" worksheet. I don't know what the significance of the "Sheet9" worksheet is from your explanation.

This is a quick piece of code that does what you want:

```
Sub copy_HT_rows()

    Dim rng As Range
    Sheets("Input").Select
    Range("A1").Select

    For Each rng In Sheets("input").Range("A1:A100")
        If rng.Value = "HT" Then
            Rows(rng.Row).Copy
            Sheets("Records").Select
            If (Range("A1") <> "") Then
                Range("A10000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            Else
                Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            End If
            Sheets("Input").Select
        End If
    Next rng
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Use autofilter

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet9").Range("A1:A1000") '<include header
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, "HT") = 0 Then Exit Sub
    rng.AutoFilter
    rng.AutoFilter 1, "HT"

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Records")
          rng.Offset(1).Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy .Range("A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1)
    End With
    rng.AutoFilter
End Sub
```