# Using VBA to create one masterfile from multiple closed files. All closed files are saved under the same folder, same format

Tags: excel, vba

After days of trying to solve this task, I found this great forum and hope you guys can help (I am rather new to VBA...).

In a nutshell, we have monthly reports with a lot of data. These monthly files are always stored in the same folder with the same format (format e.g. Overview 2018.01 final.xlsx & Overview 2018.02 final.xlsx). I am working on one Masterfile able to update automatically and fill in all necessary data from these closed workbooks.

So, currently for example we are in month August. I created an UPDATE command button and if you click it, I would like excel to get data from the file "Overview 2018.08 final.xlsx", perform a sumif function (sum all numbers linked to the ordernumber P123, P124 etc) and paste it the Masterfile.

Next month, in September I would like that once you press the command button, it updates again August data AND includes data from the September file ("Overview 2018.09 final.xlsx") and so on...

What would be the simplest code to perform that?

I hope its clear and you guys can help me. Would be really grateful.

All the best

Comment: Show us the code you've been working on this whole week and we can help you tweak it :)

Comment: This may give you a start - and I built that from examples on here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/40768023/4961700

Comment: Guys, thank you so much for your replies and help!! @Solar Mike I took some examples from your post, adapted a bit and the code starts to work. I just have another efficiency problem...I defined e.g. fromPath = Sheets("Filepaths").Range("G2") as the location of the file in the folder. In every row (G2 to G80) there is a different filename. Do I need to define every single Path (e.g. Frompath, Frompath2, Frompath3 etc..) or is there a more efficient way? Hope its clear guys and thanks again!! Huge help!!

Comment: Either the contents of G2 is the path or the filename or both - make a decision...

Comment: @Solar Mike Thank you for your reply. How can I share the code with you please? Sorry first time I am using this forum! Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect problem for Power Query -- it's a Microsoft add-on for Excel 2010/2013, and is built-in to 2016.

PQ will allow you to open, merge, and manipulate (e.g. parse, sum) the files as you described.

Good luck

Comment: Thank you Jbowman - pretty powerful tool. Need to get used to it ;)