# Macro to loop through the values of a list in a column and paste one by one into another cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet that pulls some data from yahoo finance. Another sheet contains a list of tickers. I need to copy and paste each of those tickers sequentially, waiting 10 seconds in between each subsequent ticker.

Sheet1 one (cell b1) contains the symbol used to download, while sheet2 (rance A1:A40) contains all the tickers. I am new to Excel and VBA, any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Well, I started by looking at Q&A on here and cobbling together bits, so have a look and see if you can use this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/40768023/4961700

Comment: Thanks, I did see that post but it does nothing like I need it to do.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I get your point, but you could try something similar to this (not tested):

```
Dim wb as Workbook
Dim ws_1 as Worksheet
Dim ws_2 as Worksheet

Dim ticker_coll as Collection
Dim ticker as Variant

Set ticker_coll = New Collection
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws_1 = wb.Sheets(1)
Set ws_2 = wb.Sheets(2)

'Add all tickers from sheet 2 to the collection
Dim counter as Long
For counter = 1 To 40
    ticker_coll.Add ws_2.Range("A" & counter)
Next counter

'Paste each ticker into sheet 1
For counter = 1 To 40
    ws_1.Range("B" & counter) = ticker_coll(counter)
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10")) 'Wait 10 seconds
Next counter
```