# Print multiple PDFs using VBA specifying page size

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, printing

I have found solutions to print multiple PDFs using the shell command in Excel VBA such as this:

```
Shell("C:\Program Files\Adobe\Acrobat\ Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" /s /h /t C:\Test.pdf")
```

But is there a way to specify the print settings such as the page size?

Thank you in advance for your answers

Comment: Several q & a on here about pdf printing - worth looking.

Comment: Thank you, however I have not found a solution for vba so far. Neither in this or any other forum.

Comment: I suggested it was worth looking, and I know there are some about this as I posted one myself... If you are interested, here is a link : https://stackoverflow.com/q/40702172/4961700

Comment: Thanks for the link. The issue I am dealing with is somewhat different: I have a set of PDFs (here simplified as "Test.pdf" located on my drive at "C:\") which I want to print using a macro. The code ````Shell("C:\Program Files\Adobe\Acrobat\ Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" /s /h /t C:\Test.pdf")```will print the PDF but I cannot specify the page size. Meaning I can not define if it should print in A4 or A3. I am looking for a way to specify the page size.

Comment: Then you can adapt what I had and sort it to fit your situation...

Comment: I am not trying to create a PDF from Excel. The PDF already exists (and is not created from an excel sheet). I don't see how your code could be modified to fit my situation. It has a completely different purpose

Comment: Give the macro a list of names and work through - seems similar ... somehow... But if you want someone to write a "perfect" solution then just wait...

Comment: The issue is not the list of names to work through. Of course I can make someking of loop with the different File-Names. The issue is to specify the page size when printing the PDF (an existing PDF not an excel sheet). The issue is the printing statement itself not the list or the loop

Comment: Do a search on here for "vba print setting" and check out ...