# How do I loop the below code in VBA, while stepping down each time. The loop would stop when the last step down, has no value in the cell

Tags: excel, vba, loops

'I am looking to make a print all button in Excel. I have a vertical list of all parts shipping that day. I am copying a part number and pasting on the shipping label (separate sheet). Once the part number is pasted the shipping label populates with source data from a master list via Vlookup (ie Description of part/qty/ etc).. So I would want to always start with C5 on the shipping list then copy/paste/print label/return to list/step down/select/copy/paste/print label/return to list.. if on the last step down no value is returned the function should stop. So it would be a Loop'

```
Sub print_all_test()
'
' print_all_test Macro
'
'
    Sheets("Weight Calculator").Select
    Range("C5").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("SJ Tag Print All").Select
    Range("C7:J7").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False
    Sheets("Weight Calculator").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: What does "Step down" mean? Move to the next row (so cell `C6`)?

Comment: Have a look at the loop in this - warning: I have just been told I should not be using the clipboard... but the loop , and the macro work fine :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/40768023/4961700

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming "Step down" means to move to the next row (Cell C6 after Cell C5 is processed) then:

```
Sub print_all_test()
'
' print_all_test Macro
'
'

    'Lets get this worksheet into a variable so we can reference it easier
    Dim wcSheet as Worksheet
    Set wcSheet = Sheets("Weight Calculator")

    'Declare a variable for whatever cell we are doing the print on
    Dim printCell as Range

    'Loop through cells. 
    For each printCell In Range wcSheet.Range("C5:C5000")
         'Check if printCell has a value, if not then exit this loop
         If printCell.Value = "" Then Exit For
         'Copy and Paste
         printCell.Copy Destination:=Sheets("SJ Tag Print All").Range("C7:J7")

         Sheets("SJ Tag Print All").PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, _
             IgnorePrintAreas:=False
    Next printCell

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes step down means next row (So C6, C7...) I think that might work however I am getting a compile error at: 

For each printCell In Range wcSheet.Range("C5:C5000").Cells

Comment: @KyleMartin looks like a couple typos - if I understand the question, should be `For each printCell In wcSheet.Range("C5:C5000")`, and then `printCell.Copy Destination:=Sheets("SJ Tag Print All").Range("C7:J7")`

Comment: WOW!!! That worked great!!!! Thank you so much for the assistance

Comment: Wooops! Fixed those issues in the answer. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub test()
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    lastrow = Sheets("Weight Calculator").Cells(Sheets("Weight Calculator").Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row 'Get last row in column C

    For i = 5 To lastrow
        Sheets("SJ Tag Print All").Range("C7:J7").Value = Sheets("Weight Calculator").Range("C" & i).Value
        'Do whatever else you need to do, like printing.
    Next i

End Sub
```