# To automatically print in excel but nothing happens

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

I am trying to use this code for the following:

When I click on a link in Excel it automatically prints, but nothing happens.

I have mozilla installed, the path is the same. Where could be the cause of this thing?

```
Sub PrintWebPage()
    Dim ie As Object
    Dim url As String
    Dim cell As Range
    ' Check if a hyperlink is selected
    On Error Resume Next
    Set cell = ActiveCell.Hyperlinks(1).Range
    If cell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Please select a hyperlink."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    ' Get the URL from the hyperlink
    url = cell.Hyperlinks(1).Address
    ' Open the internet page in Google Chrome
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.Navigate url
    ' Wait for page to load
    Do While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
    ' Print the page
    ie.ExecWB OLECMDID_PRINT, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER
    ' Close Google Chrome
    ie.Quit
    Set ie = Nothing
End Sub
```

the code i have posted above.

Comment: What happens when you remove `On Error Resume Next`? Put a breakpoint (F9) on the line `If cell Is Nothing Then` and then step through it (F8).

Comment: Then I guess the `ActiveCell` does not have a `Hyperlink` object associated with it.

Comment: So what is selected as the printer? I specified everything when I did this: which printer, single sided, portrait, A4 etc etc etc

Comment: Are you sure the right worksheet is selected? You may want to check `ActiveCell` first. Relying on what is active at the time is not usually the best way to write code for Excel.

Comment: Does the cell contain text that is a URL, or is it *actually a hyperlink*? i.e. if you manually click the cell yourself, does the pdf open?

Comment: How did you get this far? Like... what are you using to learn?

Comment: Check the q&a on here, there are several that deal with printing and have example code.

Comment: Have a look at what I did here: just to give a different idea: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40768023/4961700

Comment: Someone should tell/train ChatGPT to stop using internet explorer too. It seems many times it gives code like this which often has problems, mostly because it learned from old/flawed tutorials on the web.

Comment: @braX - I sense a whole new wave of questions like this, where the OP doesn't necessarily understand the code they already have. Sure, we get those already from people who have copied and pasted *working answers* but at least they **work**.

Comment: @KJ - *impossible?* - that might be a bit strong. If you have Adobe Acrobat Reader installed for instance, you could craft a shell command to open, print and close the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a rework of your routine, this time without any error ignoring to confuse things. You can also check the Immediate Window in the VB editor to debug any issues.

```
Sub PrintWebPage_v2()

    'declarations
    Dim ie As Object
    Dim URL As String
    
    Debug.Print "Running routine."
    Debug.Print "Cell selected: " & ActiveCell.Address
    Debug.Print "Workbook: " & ActiveWorkbook.Name & " on sheet " & ActiveSheet.Name

    With ActiveCell
        
        'check hyperlink exists
        If .Hyperlinks.Count = 0 Then
            Debug.Print "No hyperlinks found. Quitting."
            MsgBox "Please select a hyperlink."
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
        'grab URL
        URL = .Hyperlinks(1).Address
        Debug.Print "Hyperlink found: " & URL
        
        'Open IE
        Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        Debug.Print "IE opened."
        ie.Visible = True
        
        'Tell IE to open URL
        Debug.Print "Requesting URL"
        ie.Navigate URL
    
        'Allow IE to complete
        Do While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Loop
        Debug.Print "IE complete"
        
         ' Print the page
        ie.ExecWB OLECMDID_PRINT, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER
        Debug.Print "Print command sent."
        
        ' Quit IE
        ie.Quit
        Debug.Print "IE closed."
        
    End With

End Sub
```

The only part of the above I can't test is the `ie.ExecWB OLECMDID_PRINT` command. The rest works fine for me, opens a PDF etc.

Comment: I'm not sure if the user wants to Print **TO** PDF. The file is already a PDF. If they just want a PDF file, then just copy the source file. I think they just want to **physically print** the PDF to their printer. If that's not possible (which I accept may not be) then I'd suggest the shell route.